# Do revisionist historiographies come closer to "unbiased truth"?

Tags: historiography, revisionism

Historiography, the practice of historians, regularly revises historiographical accounts of history.  The revision of history, or "historical revisionism," often involves raising new concepts or methods.  It is very very different to the offensive and deliberately false practice of denial of genocides, which has occasionally been called "revisionism" because it sought to revise history.  So "historical revisionism" is the practice of historians revising history.

One major and well known "wave" of revisions was the development of "social history" in the West in the 1950s-1970s.  Another is the "narrative turn" in predominantly US cultural history in the 1975-1995 period.  Yet another wave of historical revision is the turn to "transnational history" in the last 20 years.

Does revisionist history come closer to the unbiased truth?  Are revisionist historiographies always more historiographically advanced and more developed in exposing "the past as it was" in terms of historiography?

Many older people learned public history from school systems, the content of these public histories varies considerably from contemporary academic accounts.  When a member of the public encounters revised academic histories, or revised public histories, how can they evaluate the "truth" content and the "bias" of the revised history?  How can they evaluate the "truth" and "bias" of the public history they learnt in school?

Comment: I would think it depends on the topic.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is intrinsically opinion oriented.  History is a living discipline and there are always new methodologies, new technologies and new discoveries that help us to understand the past.  There are also people who want to force fit history into their ideology and will "revise" to make it so.  And then there are those who are desperate for attention and use "sexy" as a substitute for "precise".

Comment: Revisionism just means changing a traditional viewpoint on a topic to reflect new information or new attitudes. For example, putting instances of allied soldiers murdering Dachau guards in history books is revisionism, because there is now less desire to paint WW2 American soldiers as uniformly good. There is always bias. Revisionism is changing what those biases are.

Comment: This needs an edit, but it is rescuable.  I'm pretty sure I could rescue it.

Comment: @SamuelRussell Well done, thank you. I accept that new question.

Comment: Sorry, but the question relies on the notion of 'unbiased truth' - a concept I reject.

Comment: I've used Ranke's "as it was" as a proxy for the general public's understanding of "unbiased."  Part of any answer would need to note the problem with "bias" as a concept in the general public.  I maintained the concept "unbiased" since it seemed a strong opinion from the original questioner.  If the OP is happy for me to further modify this to a question as a historian would write it, I will.

Answer (score 3):

"Revisionist" is typically an [insulting term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_revisionism_(negationism)) applied to attempts to change the way things are viewed, regardless of where the evidence may actually be leading. So by definition, no its not any closer to the truth. But what is "revisionist" depends on who you ask, so that's not really a useful scientific distinction.

However, its quite true that the generally-accepted view of large parts of history changes as new information comes in, and certainly we've gotten a lot of new information since the 1960's.

Also, the popular literature on History (and here I'm particularly including grade school textbooks), is heavily weighted towards what society *wants to believe* happened. That also changes over time, and of course has changed greatly since the 1960's.

One prime example of this: I'm nearly your age, and my public school had really old textbooks, so its probably fair to say that the American History texts both of us read in school were similar. Mine were heavily influenced by the [Dunning School view of Reconstruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning_School). This view was one of the prime targets of what has often been called [Historical Revisionism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_revisionism). And well targeted too. It was not only flat out wrong, but conveniently wrong in a way that lent support to segregation (and the terrorist tactics that upheld it).